# How to 'install' my own file system into my USB?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, filesystems

If I write my own file system (some basic), How do I 'install' it to my USB?, Let's say that I've written a hash table and I want to format on my USB.. How do I that? My OS is Ubuntu x86_64.

Comment: Sorry, I've downvoted the question as it the answer must depend on the file system you have created.  The USB device is nothing more then a block device so if all that was happening was a hash table you could simply write to the USB block as if it were a file - but that would not handle things like sizing problems etc.

Comment: This question indicates that the author has only the vaguest notion about  filesystems, their functions and operations. I suggest much more reading before attacking  a problem as complex as devising a new filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you first play with new filesystems by writing them to files, and not devices. It will ease your development and testing.

```
 # create a 4MB file called 'myfs' with just zeros
 dd if=/dev/zero of=myfs bs=1 count=0 seek=4M
 # then use your tool to create the custom filesystem on myfs
```

Once you have your filesystem written in a file, you may copy that to the USB key. If you plug in your USB drive/key, event scripts will assign it a device name. You will need the device name to install your own filesystem on it. You can get its name by looking at `dmesg` after you plug it in.

```
# plug in the USB key and wait 2 seconds
$ dmesg | less
# hit shift+G to see the end of the file, q to quit
```

For a USB card reader, you would see something like:

```
[  740.925402] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  741.061264] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0732
[  741.061270] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[  741.061275] usb 2-2: Product: USB Reader
[  741.061278] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Genesys 
[  741.061282] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 000000000712
[  741.340371] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
...
[  742.380447] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdf] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

The file `/dev/sdf` here will allow one to interact directly with what's stored on the memory card. You have to be careful to select the device node for the usb key and not, say, a hard drive you depend on. If there was a partition table on that memory card, the partitions would be available under `/dev/sdf[n]` where n is the number of the partition.
Ubuntu will automatically mount filesystems it recognizes under `/media/<username>/<label>`. To play around with your own filesystem format, it will be likely that you'll have to `umount` those first.

You may copy your filesystem-in-a-file `myfs` to the usb key using the `dd` tool:

```
# WARN: backup your files on the key, because this is a very
#       destructive operation.

# directly on the device (no partition table)
$ sudo dd if=myfs of=/dev/sdf

# -- OR --

# if you have a partition table, you could write it only to one
# of the partitions e.g.:
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdf  # create the partitions
$ sudo dd if=myfs of=/dev/sdf1  # for the first partition
```

**Registering the new custom filesystem**

You may implement new filesystems with `FUSE`, which will allow you to do things such as:

```
# mycustomfs is a program you write in the language you want.
# myfs is your filesystem in a file.
# /mnt/contents could be the target where you want the fs to be mounted
$ mycustomfs myfs  /mnt/contents/
```

Here is a tutorial for a FS written in Ruby: https://www.debian-administration.org/article/619/Creating_Filesystems_with_Ruby__and_FUSE

And once you have that working, you may register your new custom filesystem so that `mount` knows what to do with it.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554178/how-to-register-fuse-filesystem-type-with-mount8-and-fstab